# How to read bash script-style config more safely?

Tags: bash, config

Easy way:

```
# Read environment from config file

set -o allexport
source my_config_file.conf
set +o allexport
```

Format of the config file is like that:

```
VAR1=eee
VAR2="dsfsdf sd fsdf"
VAR3=$VAR1
# comment
```

How to do it more safely (allowing some expansions, but without actually executing commands in config file). The "safety" should protect from occasional inserting of wrong snippets into config, not from specially crafted attacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VAR1=eee` is a command, so which commands do you want to stop?  Let's assume it is external programs.

One way would be to trash PATH:

```
oldPATH="$PATH"
PATH=
set -o allexport 
source /full-path-name/my_config_file.conf 
set +o allexport 
PATH="$oldPATH"
```

But wait!  Commands are "hashed", so you need to clear the hash first as well, so add `hash -r`.
You might also need to clear aliases as well, for example `ls` is often an alias.

This is easily curcumvented by supplying the full path name of the command, for example `/usr/bin/man`, but that's about the limit of what you can do.

Comment: Maybe there are tools apart from "bash" that reads such files? I expected something like `env --file=myenvironment.conf program`.

Comment: Is unsetting PATH enough to stop most random code (various script snippets) to work?

Comment: Why don't you examine the file first, then bail if it contains anything else than simple assignments?

Comment: Too complicated. Better use PATH/hash hack and/or use different config format at all.

Comment: Not at all. Just a basic grep. Quoted strings may be a bit challenging but perhaps you don't need to or want to support the full scale of what the shell can do. You could require all values to be single tokens, for example.

Comment: @Vi.:Maybe you should turn it around and only allow assignments?  A simple `if grep -v '=' config-file >/dev/null` should suffice.

Comment: @cdarke, No, I think `SHUTDOWN_SETTING=without halt` can be common sort of mistake. And unsetting PATH can help to stop them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict the .conf file to only allow some allowable patterns, you could do something along the lines of:

```
eval `awk -v FS="=[\"]*" -v RS="[\"]*\n" '/^[A-Z0-9]+=/ { printf("export %s=\"%s\"; ", \$1, \$2); }' my_config_file.conf`;
```

The regex in the awk scriptlet can be flexible or strict along the lines of `^((VAR1)|(VAR2)|(VAR3))=`.

`.` is still used to "run" the assignments, but only "acceptable" lines are run from the .conf file.  The pattern above filters all lines that do not look like simple assignments of variables made up of uppercase alpha and numeric characters.  Fancier regex expressions could allow more cases or flexibility.  RS above means that trailing quotes are ignored.  FS says that if a quote follows the = then it is ignored.  FS/RS combined result in stripping quotes from values.  The output is transformed to only statements like `export VAR="VALUE"`.

This does not protect from "attacks" as the value is not parsed at all, but such filtering could be added easily enough.

Comment: Looks overly complicated for "just to be a little safer" task.

Comment: Perhaps, so I rewrote the answer as a one-liner without use of a temporary file.  Nevertheless, for other people visiting this question, perhaps the level of safety vs. minor complexity is warranted.

Comment: Somewhat baffling to come here for security advice and then deem the effort "too complicated", even for a few lines of documented code.